# Check if a VPN connection is active in Android and show a message?

Tags: android, vpn, android-vpn-service

I have a third party VPN app on my non-rooted Android 4.4 device, and want to write a background service to monitor the VPN connection and alert the user if the VPN connection is on.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
public static boolean isVpnConnectionActive(){
    List<String> networks = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())) {
            if (networkInterface.isUp()){
                networks.add(networkInterface.getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    return networks.contains("tun") || networks.contains("ppp") || networks.contains("pptp");
}
```

Comment: how can i sure about "tun0"? can it be "tun1 or 2 or 3" ?

Comment: @WasiSadman no, it is always `tun0`, but you can use `tun` instead of `tun0` to check all possible conditions. I will update the answer.

Comment: well i found for my app **tun1**